# Is there a way to have a dynamically grouped grid in Java FX 8 similar to the KendoUI Grid?

Tags: javafx-8

I am looking for a control out there which can replicate the grouping functionality of the KendoUI Grid, which allows users to select specific columns to group on.

All I have seen in JavaFX is the TreeTableView which is not quite what I needed.  A sample of the functionality can be found here: [Kendo Grid](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index)

I would like to be able to allow users at runtime to define their own grouping as it suits them.

Here is a screen shot: Ungrouped
[image]

Grouped:

[image]

Basically - the users would like to decide their own grouping settings in a way that makes sense.

Comment: Looks like a [TreeTableView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/tree-table-view.htm), you should probably start with that and adapt it to your needs.

Comment: I realize they are similar, but not quite the same.  This is a groupable table based on a tabular dataset.  The TableTreeView requires a treeview structure predefined.  This is not how the data is formatted, and since it's dynamic, restructuring on the fly would be problematic.

Comment: What is your question then?  What would you expect in an answer?

Comment: I am asking if there is a control out there that performs a similar function on tabular data.

Answer (score 0):

No such control exists in the standard JavaFX toolkit or any 3rd party library I am aware of.

Creating a similar control from scratch would be a large and difficult task.  It is, of course, possible to do it, just not straight-forward.

[TreeTableView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/tree-table-view.htm) is the closest thing.  You can investigate customizing the TreeTableView to get the functionality you require. Customizing TreeTableView may or may not be a good approach.  Alternately, you could build the UI up by compositing separate controls, e.g., TitledPanes, VBox, ScrollPane, Pagination, etc.  That might be a better approach.

I have no further pointers on how you would go about writing customized code to get this functionality.  Creating a sample solution for this is outside the standard scope of a StackOverflow answer.

The KendoUI element you reference is a HTML based control.  If you wish, you could embed it in JavaFX using a WebView, rather than developing a native JavaFX control for the functionality.

Comment: I have considered using the webview, but that doesn't really satisfy what I am looking for.  Hopefully someone out there will know of such a control, or maybe be encouraged to look into building one.  I have considered dynamically creating the tree structure and table on the fly as well - but am not sure as to the long term viability of such an approach as more and more tables need this behavior, including the ability to save this off.  thanks for the input though.